# Why href inside button not working?

Tags: ionic-framework, href

```
<button class="button button-outline button-positive">
    <a href="www.google.com">fes</a>
</button>
```

If I use `ng-click`, it's works fine, but I need `href`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Drop the button and decorate the `a` element with the class names.

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="button button-outline button-positive">fes</a>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know about OP, but it sure helped me. I had the same problem and couldn't figure out what was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in html page:

```
<button menuClose ion-item (click)="openExternalPage(urlCgu)"><ion-icon name="ios-paper-outline" color="primary" item-start ></ion-icon> Conditions d'utilisation</button>
```

in ts page:

```
urlCgu:string;
this.urlCgu = 'http://xxxxxxx.com';

openExternalPage(page){
    window.open(page);
}
```

Comment: Might want to add a bit to the answer what the changes/differences are instead of just posting code.